# How do I loop through this array with a foreach loop?

Tags: php

I'd like to loop through my array with a `foreach` loop but I'm having mixed results.

The array below is stored in a variable `$result`.

When I run `foreach ($result as $call) {` it only loops once despite having 3 items in the array. Why is that happening?

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CallRef] => 1025742698
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [CallRef] => 1025786953
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [CallRef] => 1025786953
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: it is an array containing *one* element, which is an array that contains *three* elements. the solution: *loop over the inner array*.

Comment: Actually, `$result` only have one array item. It is _that_ Item has three items.

Comment: You have to look carefully, you can't just ignore the `[item]` in the dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is multidimensional, so your first array has only 1 index; thus 1 result, which happens to be another array.

You'd want to do something like this.

```
foreach($result['item'] as $res){
    //some action
}
```

More info here: [Looping a multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551822/looping-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: There is no `$result[0]`, it should be `$result['item']`.

Comment: Didn't notice the inner array was associative. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Many thanks, @Kaylined - you've been a brilliant help for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($result['item'] as $item){
   echo $item['CallRef']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
   foreach ($result['item'] as $key => $value)
      {
       echo $value['CallRef']."<br/>"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with it. If your main array like below:

```
$data=array('item' => array(array('CallRef' => 1025742698),array('CallRef' => 1025786953), array('CallRef' => 1025786953)));

foreach($data['item'] as $data_res)
{
    echo $data_res['CallRef']."</br>";
}
```